# Google Sheets edited(with Python) via user input embedded on Google Site

Tags: python, gspread

What I am trying to do is build a script that I can embed into my Google Site. I have used Trinket.io to embed simple scripts into my site successfully.

I want students to log on to my Google Site and see a prompt for input (trinket.io) where they can input data that will then be stored in a Google Sheet. (I have already been able to connect and manipulate Google Sheets with the gspread module.)

Ultimately, I am hoping to give students a “credit card” that they can track purchases (the input I am hoping they will be able to log in the Google Site). From there, I was hoping to automatically calculate, interest rates, balances, and weekly statements that will be emailed to each student.

I am just stuck right now because I do not know how to take my script that connects to the Google Sheet, and make it available as a run only code for students, embedded into my Google Site.

Comment: Have you been able to use Trinket.io to embed any Python script in your Google Site so far?

Comment: Yes. I created a grade calculator, choose your own adventure game, and a few other very simple scripts.